# Default value/load value in Html.DropDownListFor

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, html-helper

Cant find any solution to have another value as default when entering the page. It's always my first value.

Creating the "selectlist"

```
            List<SelectListItem> list = new List<SelectListItem>();
        var x = 0;
        foreach (var lang in Enum.GetValues(typeof(ResourceHandler.Languages)))
        {
            list.Add(new SelectListItem { Selected = x == langInt, Value = x++.ToString(), Text = lang.ToString() });
        }
```

viewmodel:

```
    public class SettingsViewModel
{
    public int LanguageId { get; set; }
    public List<SelectListItem> Language { get; set; }
}
```

View:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(x=>x.LanguageId, new SelectList(Model.Language,"Value","Text"))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not supply the default language as a parameter? Another thing, changing the List to a SelectList makes things easier.

```
public class SettingsViewModel
{
    public int LanguageId { get; set; }
    public SelectList Language { get; set; }
    public int? DefaultLanguageId {get; set;}

    public SettingsViewModel()
    {
       CreateSelectList();
    }     

    public SettingsViewModel(int? defaultLanguageId)
    {
        DefaultLanguageId = defaultLanguageId;
        CreateSelectList();
    }

    private void CreateSelectList()
    {
        List<SelectListItem> list = new List<SelectListItem>();
        var x = 0;
        foreach (var lang in Enum.GetValues(typeof(ResourceHandler.Languages)))
        {
            list.Add(new SelectListItem { Selected = x == langInt, Value = x++.ToString(), Text = lang.ToString() });

            if(DefaultLanguageId != null)
               SelectList = new SelectList(list, "Value", "Text", DefaultLanguageId)
            else
               SelectList = new SelectList(list, "Value", "Text") 
        }
    }
```

Then the view:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.LanguageId, Model.Language)
```

Comment: Nicer structure then me but it doesnt help to get the default/pre selected/selectedValue to be preselected at startup/entering the page. As before I have false to all of my languages without one that is true to my "selectedValue". Order the list and put the "selectedValue" at top feels incorrect! Btw I changed "SelectList" in the last "If" to "Language"

Comment: Finally! Missed to set LanguageId to defaultLangugageId. So in my SettingsViewModel(int? defaultLAnguageId) I now added LanguageId = defaultLanguageId.GetValueOrDefault(); And now it works

Comment: @DavidLarsson Hopes its help you! :)

Answer (score 6):

You can use [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee703561%28v=vs.108%29.aspx) overload of the DropDownList for extension method.

It will be something like this

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(x=>x.LanguageId, new SelectList(Model.Language,"Value","Text"),"--Choose A Language --")
```

Comment: I know that exist. But what I want is that eg item 3 is preselected.

Comment: In that case you should provide the item 3 as 3rd argument in `new SelectList(Model.Language,"Value","Text",selectedValue)`

Comment: Tried that before but what is selectedValue? I cant reach x.SelectedValue, tried for a test to write 0 or "aTextThatAreTextValue"'

Comment: Wrote on wrong post, so I deleted my comment before your "Fine". Thanks anyway :)